# edit array value with php

Tags: php, str-replace

I have an output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post] => john Has site <a href='http://www.mysite.com/events/info/4240'>this is a test</a>
            [date_created] => 1341853220
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post] => jane Has site <a href='http://www.mysite.com/events/info/1'>test venue</a>
            [date_created] => 1341849999
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post] => james Has site <a href='http://www.mysite.com/events/info/4240'>this is a test</a>
            [date_created] => 1341680695
        )
```

I want to know if there is any way to get result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post] => john Has site this is a test
            [number] => 4240
            [date_created] => 1341853220
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post] => jane Has site test venue
            [number] => 1
            [date_created] => 1341849999
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post] => james Has site this is a test
            [number] => 4240
            [date_created] => 1341680695
        )
```

what I want is to eliminate the html tags along with the url and just keep the name and the number at the end of the url so that i can store it and use it later.
I was trying to use str_replace inside a foreach but I cant find the right way to do it or is there another way to accomplish this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Match the href using the RegEx: `<a href='([^\']+?)'>`.
2. `explode()` the matched string with delimiter '`/`'.
3. Get the last element which is `number`.
4. Construct a new array of objects with stripped tag `post` and new element `number`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Regular Expression, as Shubham mentioned.

Using PHP's [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) and the following pattern, the required data can be retrieved from the post. Afterwards a new array can be created with the desired result.

`#(.+)<a[^>]+?([0-9]+)'>(.+)</a>#`